# How to add <br> tag in PHP Date format

Tags: php, datetime

Is there a way to add a line break 
 in PHP date formats? 
I am using a plugin for WordPress which allows for the use of regular PHP date formats and have tried numerous options but not gotten something to work yet.

What I have tried:

- l `</br>` j M
- l \n j M

Thanks!

Comment: I'd have thought you need to output the date twice, selecting the bits you want with a line break between the two.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

```
echo date("l<\b\\r>j M");
```

or

```
echo date('l<\b\r>j M');
```

Outputs:

```
Wednesday<br>2 Jan
```

Comment: Why do you need double backslash before `r`?

Comment: Because \r is carriage return and I put it in double quotes. You only need one backslash if you wrap the text inside single quotes.

Answer (score 9):

You need to escape the HTML tag to avoid it being parsed as date segments:

```
<?php
    echo date('l \<\/\b\r\> j M');
?>
```

Alternatively, if you don’t like the above (like me), then you can use the [strftime()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strftime.php) function:

```
<?php
    echo strftime('%A<br />%e %b');
?>
```

The second parameters of both the `date()` and `strftime()` functions takes a timestamp.

Comment: strftime is locale aware though, so the result may not be the same as with date. but yes, both valid approaches.

Answer (score 2):

On the [`date()`](http://php.net/date) function PHP manual page is the following paragraph:

> You can prevent a recognized character in the format string from being expanded by escaping it with a preceding backslash. If the character with a backslash is already a special sequence, you may need to also escape the backslash.

---

To use your example format, the properly escaped characters would be like:

```
'l<\b\r/>j M'
"l<\\b\\r/>j M"
```

The second example is double escaped since `\b` and `\r` are meaningful escape sequences in double-quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
date('l<\b\\r />j M')
```

Will make a date string like:

```
l<br />j M
```

Which comes out like:

```
Wednesday<br />2 Jan
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for your inputs. I then stumbled on some additional documentation where I could use the dates like this. No doubt, your answers will come in use for me someday again ;)

The plugin I am using is Events Manager and this was the solution for others who might want it:

```
    <div class="ev_body">
    <span class="ev_icon">#_CATEGORYIMAGE</span>
    <span class="ev_category">#_CATEGORY</span>
    <span class="ev_weekday">#l</span>
    <span class="ev_day">#j</span>
    <span class="ev_month">#M</span>
    <span class="ev_time">#_EVENTTIMES</span>
    <span class="ev_link">#_EVENTLINK {has_location}<br/><i>#_LOCATIONNAME, #_LOCATIONTOWN #_LOCATIONSTATE</i>{/has_location}
    </span>
    </div>
```

Where the #l, #j, #M etc are the PHP date formats.