# Is it possible to add word wrap in php date()

Tags: php, html, templates

I need to print result of function `date('d-m-y H:i:s', $time)` on two lines like this:

```
26-11-2019 
10:00:02
```

I try to add `<br/>` between 'd-m-y' AND 'H:i:s' doesn't help.

Comment: Of course the easiest way is to print date('d-m-y', $time) <br/> date('H:i:s', $time)

Comment: mdBender  your code will result in error.

Comment: Simply try this echo date('d-m-y')."<br/>".date('H:i:s');

Comment: Thank you! I print it like explain of my thoughts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use simple PHP date function with escape sequences `<\b\r>`

```
echo date('d-m-y <\b\r>H:i:s');
```

**Output**

27-11-19

00:45:55

Referance: [How to add <br> tag in PHP Date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14122276/how-to-add-br-tag-in-php-date-format)

Comment: Why I was trying to escape all tag <br/>? :) I try to print date('d-m-y \<\b\r\/\> H:i:s') and It it doesn't work. Thanks for answer, works great!

Comment: Welcome @mdBender, Keep Coding

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
echo nl2br(date("d-m-y\nH:i:s", $time));
```

Note that I used double quotes instead of single quotes.
This is because \n won't work with single quotes.
For your reference:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php
[What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

Try like this may it will help.

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<?php 
     echo date('d-m-y', $time) . "<br>" . date('H:i:s', $time) 
?>

</body>
<html>
```